# List of AutoCompleteTextField not visible (is drawing behind softKeyboard)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, autocompletetextview

I have a problem, which I cannot solve ...

I have a activity where the user could add some information like name and so one. It is written in Kotlin with the Jetpack Compose library. One field is an AutoCompleteTextView where the systems gets information from a room database and display the stuff on a list below the textField. My problem is that this list is always shown behind the keyboard. (as show in the pictures below). How can I manage that the list is shown / scrolled into view? (the "InputFields" are located inside a scrollable column). When displaying the list above the textField then there is another problem: I lost the focus of the textField ...

[image: Without List]

[image: List is not shown/scrolled]

[image: How it should be]

My Code:

AutoCompleteView:

```
@Composable
fun <T> AutoCompleteTextView(
modifier: Modifier,
value: String,
label: String,
onValueChanged: (String) -> Unit = {},
predictions: List<T>,
clearVisible: Boolean = true,
keyBoardAction: ImeAction = ImeAction.Search,
onActionClick: () -> Unit = {},
onClearClick: () -> Unit = {},
onItemClick: (T) -> Unit = {},
itemContent: @Composable (T) -> Unit = {},
) {
val view = LocalView.current
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
var showClearButton by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
LazyColumn(
    state = lazyListState,
    modifier = modifier.heightIn(max = TextFieldDefaults.MinHeight * 6)
) {

    item {
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = modifier
                .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                    showClearButton = clearVisible and focusState.isFocused
                }
                .focusRequester(focusRequester),
            value = value,
            onValueChange = {
                onValueChanged.invoke(it)
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            },
            label = { Text(text = label) },
            singleLine = true,
            trailingIcon = {
                if (showClearButton) {
                    IconButton(painterResource(R.mipmap.ic_close), 
                    stringResource(R.string.clear)) {
                        onClearClick()
                    }
                }
            },
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onSearch = { onActionClick() },
                onDone = { onActionClick() },
                onGo = { onActionClick() },
                onNext = { onActionClick() },
                onPrevious = { onActionClick() },
                onSend = { onActionClick() },
            ),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                imeAction = keyBoardAction,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
            ),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                focusedIndicatorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = 
MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
                focusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
                errorContainerColor = Color.Transparent
            )
        )
    }

    if (predictions.isNotEmpty()) {
        itemsIndexed(predictions) { _, element ->
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .padding(5.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable {
                        view.clearFocus()
                        onItemClick(element)
                    }
            ) {
                itemContent(element)
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Activity:

```
   Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(5.dp)
                ) {
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 10.dp),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, 
   MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer)
                    ) {
                        Column {
                            Row(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth()) {
                                Image(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .verticalGradient()
                                        .padding(start = 15.dp, top = 20.dp, end = 
   10.dp)
                                        .size(24.dp),
                                    painter = painterResource(R.mipmap.ic_dice),
                                    contentDescription = 
   stringResource(R.string.genres)
                                )
                                Column(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()) {
                                    FlowRow(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .wrapContentSize()
                                            .padding(vertical = 6.dp),
                                        horizontalArrangement = 
  Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp, Start),
                                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
                                    ) {
                                        for (genre in genres) {
                                            FilterChip(
                                                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal 
   = 5.dp),
                                                onClick = { genres.remove(genre) },
                                                selected = true,
                                                trailingIcon = {
                                                    Image(
                                                        modifier = Modifier
                                                            .verticalGradient()
                                                            .size(15.dp),
                                                        painter = 
   painterResource(R.mipmap.ic_close),
                                                        contentDescription = 
   stringResource(R.string.delete)
                                                    )
                                                },
                                                label = {
                                                    Text(genre.name)
                                                }
                                            )
                                        }
                                    }
                                    Box(
                                        Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth()
                                            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
                                            .height(1.dp)
                                            
   .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer)
                                    )
                                    AutoCompleteTextView(modifier = 
   Modifier.padding(5.dp),
                                        value = selectedGenreName,
                                        label = "Genre",
                                        onValueChanged = {
                                            selectedGenreName = it
                                            if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                                                getGenres(it)
                                            } else {
                                                filteredGenres.clear()
                                            }
                                        },
                                        predictions = filteredGenres,
                                        keyBoardAction = ImeAction.Done,
                                        clearVisible = false,
                                        onActionClick = {
                                            val first = filteredGenres.stream().filter 
   { it.name == selectedGenreName }.findFirst()
                                            if (first.isPresent) {
                                                genres.add(first.get())
                                            } else {
                                                genres.add(Genre().apply { name = 
   selectedGenreName })
                                            }
                                            selectedGenreName = ""
                                            filteredGenres.clear()
                                        },
                                        onItemClick = {
                                            genres.add(it)
                                            selectedGenreName = ""
                                            filteredGenres.clear()
                                        }) {
                                        Text(text = it.name)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
                                .horizontalGradient(),
                            text = stringResource(R.string.genres),
                            fontSize = 14.sp
                        )
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the activity tag that holds this screen on the manifest file and the keyboard will push the screen up

Comment: This doesn't help :(. The list still appears behind the keyboard and is doesn't scroll to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed it (with a little 'hack')

For this solution to get work I had to placed the Box at the end of the scrollable column.

Then I had to add:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to the manifest (to the activity I used) and had to add:

```
Modifier.imePadding()
```

to the scrollable column (in order to put the bottom of the column to the top of the keyboard)

Then on recompose the autocomplete view I set

```
 scope.launch { scrollState.animateScrollTo(scrollState.maxValue) }
```

So it always scroll to the end and so the list is visible.